# Avoid logging out users on Firebase Authentication migration

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

My current iOS react native app is connect to a Firebase instance (let's call it instance A) and I'm using the Authentication email/password module offered by Firebase. I would like to migrate to a new Firebase instance (let's call it instance B). I've migrated the user's auth data to instance B using Firebase's `admin.auth().importUsers` function.

However the user gets logged out when the app is updated. Any ideas on how to make this transition smooth so that the user is not forced to re-login?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is going to be possible.  The Firebase Auth SDK persists the ID token for a **specific** account that was signed in to a **specific** project.  That ID token simply isn't going to work for a different project, even if it's the an account with the same properties copied during a migration.  You'll need to allow the user to get a new ID token by signing in to the new project.